# Update attribute with array insertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, attributes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Impression` model with an `actions` attribute that is serialized for `Array`.

```
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :actions, Array
end
```

Normal attribute updating procedure:
`impression.update(some_attr: "new_value")`

Normal array insertion procedure:
`impression.actions << "new_value"`
`impression.save`

Is there a way to insert a new value to an array attribute that works like the `.update` method, i.e. in one single expression?

Comment: I had put the `ruby-on-rails-4` tag because the `.update` syntax is different for earlier versions (I think).

Comment: I've reverted the tag cancellation. `update` in Rails 4 is the same of `update_attributes` before, but I agree the tags makes sense here. Sorry for the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible when using the ActiveRecord serialization feature because the serialization/deserialization must be controller by ActiveRecord and `update` performs a direct SQL update call on the database.

Some non-relational database (such as MongoDB) offers this feature because they are designed in order to do so. PostgreSQL provides a Hash extension you can install that would allow you to perform direct operations on the serialized field.

In all the other cases, you could potentially update the field directly, but I don't encourage you to do so. There is a potential risk to write corrupted data.

Instead, I suggest you to create a custom method that performs both the push and save. In any case, this is a good idea because you are exposing a custom API outside the model instead of coupling your model to the ActiveRecord architecture.

```
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :actions, Array

  def add_action(action)
    self.actions << action
    self.save
  end
end
```

The you can use

```
impression = ...
impression.add_action "new_value"
```